# windows環境下でmmapを使用した共有メモリに対してR/Wが動作しない

Tags: python, python3

mmapを使用して名前付きの共有メモリ(RAM)上でデータのやり取りをしたいと考えています。
下記のプログラムを実行して読み出すと全て0になっており、期待値としては、書き込んだ(128, 256)でした。
動作の確認環境(開発環境)はwindows10, python3.9.5です。

mmapを選択した経緯としては、multiprocessingモジュールのSharedMemoryが、
unixでは動作しないという情報がネットにあり、今回のプログラムをunix上でも動作させる可能性があるため、
mmapを選択しました。

read_memory()の動作を単体で確認するため、
共有メモリへ書き込みをするプログラム(c++)を作成し、同一PC内で動作させて正常に読み込みは確認できました。
そのため、write_memory()の問題かと考えているのですが、
mmapの使い方の作法の問題なのか、同一プロセス内で共有メモリのW->Rは不可なのか、原因がわからずにいます。
どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか。

実装コード

```
import mmap
import struct

def read_memory():
  handle = mmap.mmap(0, 8, 'sample', mmap.ACCESS_READ)
  byte_data = handle.read()
  print('read byte:' + (str(byte_data)))
  shared_memory_info = struct.unpack('<II', byte_data)
  print('read data:' + (str(shared_memory_info)))
  handle.close()

def write_memory():
  handle = mmap.mmap(0, 8, 'sample', mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
  byte_data = struct.pack('<II', 128, 256)
  print('write byte:' + (str(byte_data)))
  handle.write(byte_data)
  handle.close()

def main():
  write_memory()
  read_memory()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

実行結果

```
write byte:b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00'
read byte:b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
read data:(0, 0)
```

Comment: 「multiprocessingモジュールのSharedMemoryが、unixでは動作しない」という情報源を教えて下さい。

Comment: 反応が遅くなり申し訳ございません、以下の記事を参考にしておりました。
https://zenn.dev/quag_cactus/articles/6d09787323d1b1#fn-d2fa-2

https://atchicken.com/shared_memory/

Comment: 前者の記事は根拠が記されていないように見え, 後者ではプログラム構造に問題があるように見えます。① 別のプロセスの起動方法はどの様な予定ですか？ (`multiprocessing` 介しての起動でも構わないか, コマンドラインなどからの起動か)。② 共有データはビジーループで書き出すようなものですか？

Comment: @oriri 

反応遅くなり申し訳ございません。
回答致します。

＞①
unix環境下での使用は可能性としてありますが、現状どういった形式かは未定です。
windows環境下ではexe形式で2つのアプリを起動予定です。
1つは記載しておりますような共有メモリにR/Wするpythonアプリ(Aアプリ)です。
もう1つは言語未定(Bアプリ)です。

やりたい事としては、2つのexe間で名前付きの共有メモリを2つ持ち、
片方はAアプリが書き込み専用、もう片方はBアプリが書き込み専用として定義して、情報のやり取りをしたいです。
データのやり取りができれば、mmapでもmultiprocessingモジュールのSharedMemoryでも問題ないです。

＞②
はい、共有メモリからビジーループでR/Wする予定です。

Comment: 答えがどちらも予想外でした。変化があったときのみ更新する などで 1秒に 1回程度の書き込みなら Linux版共有メモリーも動くかもしれません (保証はできないが)。また closeのエラーはこれかもしれません[SharedMemory.close() destroys memory](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91044)
これだとするなら (Windowsも含め) それぞれの環境によって何かしらの問題抱えているようです (「unixでは動作しない」ではなく)。(Windows版でも) issuesに記されてる使い方と同様なら同じ問題が出るかもしれない

Comment: mmap 使うなら, file1, file2 などに割り当てれば, closeしても消えません。ファイル使わない理由なにかありますか？

Comment: @oriri リンクありがとうございます。そうすると、物理的にファイルへ割り当てた方が安全そうですね。ファイルに割り当てないのは、exe実行時にファイルの管理（既にあったらどうする、途中で誰かがたまたま消したらなど）をしたくなかった位です。他に何か制限があるわけではないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux で動作確認した修正例です。

- 無名メモリにマップするために `mmap.mmap` には `fileno` として（0 では無く） -1 を渡す
- `tagname` の指定は Unix でサポートされていないので、使用しない
- 同じ `mmap` オブジェクトを使う（よって、少なくとも読む前には `seek` しておく必要が有る）

```py
import mmap
import struct


def read_memory(handle: mmap.mmap):
    handle.seek(0)
    byte_data = handle.read()
    print("read byte:" + (str(byte_data)))
    shared_memory_info = struct.unpack("<II", byte_data)
    print("read data:" + (str(shared_memory_info)))


def write_memory(handle: mmap.mmap):
    handle.seek(0)
    byte_data = struct.pack("<II", 128, 256)
    print("write byte:" + (str(byte_data)))
    handle.write(byte_data)


def main():
    # ファイルを使用する場合
    #with open("tmp.map", "r+") as mapfile, mmap.mmap(
    #    mapfile.fileno(), 8, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE
    #) as handle:

    with mmap.mmap(-1, 8, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE) as handle:
        write_memory(handle)
        read_memory(handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
mmapのhandleを破棄すると、共有メモリも破棄されるのですね。
プログラム全体が終了するまで、共有メモリは保持され続けるのかと勘違いしておりました。
記載頂いたコードを元にwindows側でも修正して確認致しました。

Answer (score 2):

(別解に コメントでファイル割り当ても記されてるが,
ファイルの扱い含めたコードとして)

mmapでファイルを割り当て, 毎回オープン・クローズする方法

- ファイルが存在したら利用し, 無かったら作成
- ファイルサイズが少し大きい程度ならそのままで構わないが, 足りない場合 `mm.resize()` などで合わせる必要がある

(Linuxで動作確認)

```py
import mmap
import struct

def read_memory(mm):
    # こういったアクセスも可能(念の為)。この場合 mm.seek(0) の指定は必要ない
    shared_memory_info = struct.unpack('<II', mm[0:8])
    print('read data:' + (str(shared_memory_info)))

def write_memory(mm):
    fmt = '<II'
    mm[0:0 +struct.calcsize(fmt)] = struct.pack(fmt, 1234, 567)

def main():
    from pathlib import Path
    fname = Path('file1.bin')

    if not fname.exists():
        with fname.open('wb') as fp:
            fp.truncate(8)

    with fname.open('r+b') as fp, mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0) as mm:
        write_memory(mm)
    with fname.open('r+b') as fp, mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0) as mm:
        read_memory(mm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答頂きました実装を参考にさせて頂き、ファイルを使用した実装に変更致しました。